# Calculation of Bayesian Information Criterion for EM algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, bayesian

The formula for calculating BIC is given by,

```
BIC = -log(data/theta) - (# of parameter / 2) * log(n).
```

Suppose the following is the case:

2D Gaussian data with `number of samples(n) = 500` and `number of clusters(K) = 4`.

What is `# of parameters` here?

The simplest logic (according to me) here is `# of parameters = K * 3 = 12. k * 3` because there are three parameters (`mu`, `sigma` and `prior`) for each of the `k = 4` classes.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data dimensionality is `d`, your mean vector probably has `d` variables and your covariance matrix has `d^2` variables.

So I'd say you have `(2 + 2 * 2 + 1) * 4 = 28` variables.

Comment: Should we consider 4 prior ? Some interpretations say that since priors add up to one it is sufficient to take 3 priors into consideration since the 4th can be derived from the 3.

Comment: Yes. You may also want to reduce the matrix cost because of symmetry. So I'd be okay if you consider this to be only (2+3+1)*4-1=23 variables. But I havn't studied BIC in detail; I'm quite skeptical about any approach that involves a single statistical number. Reality doesn't reduce to a single number.